# New Answers to Old Questions layout is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The ["New Answers to Old Questions"-View](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) in the 10k Tools layout is broken:

[image]

Comment: reproduced in chrome  on linux. (Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit))

Comment: reproduced in chrome on Windows. Version 49.0.2623.110 m

Comment: reproduced in Safari 9.0

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Fix for this should be live in up to ~24h.

Comment: @Paweł Should this be [tag:status-completed] now?

Comment: @svick yeap, status updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. Thank you for reporting it.